# Spring security not working even if I have a configuration for it

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

i have so much trouble to identify why Spring security is not working on my project.
There is my code :

```
import com.corp.myproject.config.security.filters.JwtAuthorizationFilter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.formLogin().loginPage("http://localhost:8081/login/openidProvider");
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

But I can access to my backend without any authentication.

The expected result is :

- If a user don't have a authorization jwt, Spring security redirects him to the custom login url to login in with Openid
- When the user logs in, he is redirected to my backend with a jwt
- Every requests to my backend will be filtred by my JwtAuthorizationFilter

EDIT : Adding the JwtAuthorizationFilter's code :

```
import com.corp.myproject.config.security.JwtTokenUtil;
import com.corp.myproject.config.security.UserFromToken;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorizationToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authorizationToken != null && authorizationToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String jwt = authorizationToken.substring(7); // Ignore 'Bearer '
            String error = "";
            if (!jwtTokenUtil.isTokenIntegritySafe(jwt)) {
                error = "Token jwt is not valid";
            }
            if (!jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwt)) {
                error = "Token jwt is expired";
            }
            UserFromToken userFromToken = jwtTokenUtil.getUserFromToken(jwt);
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String r : userFromToken.getRoles()) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r));
            }
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userFromToken.getName(), null, authorities);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            if (error == "") {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                response.setHeader("error-message", error);
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
            }
        } else {
            response.setHeader("error-message", "User not authorized");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the content of your `JwtAuthorizationFilter`. Remember that if you want to work with JWT Spring Security has support for oauth2 resource servers

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio it's done.
I have a special configuration in my project. ProjectA (which have this spring security config) is my application. I need to redirect the user on ProjectB's url which call OauthServer, generate my JWT and redirects the user on ProjectA's endpoint to add the roles in the JWT.

Comment: What does your request look like? What is the endpoint?